# How to play with the AudioRecord 'audioData' the right way?

Tags: android, audio, processing, audiorecord, digital

I want to ask about the 'audioData' values for AudioRecord .. :

-What is the unite for the values that i'm getting or what does the values represent?
-What is the MIN and MAX values for the raw data that i'm getting?

-Is it possible to apply some 'Digital Audio Processing' filters to the raw data? before writing it to the AudioTrack .. I'm streaming the sound .. so it goes directly to AudioTrack

-I would like to visualize the data on my PC.. so I can see the effects of the applied filters .. what would you recommend?

thanks ,,,

Comment: 1) Depends on the number of bits per sample. For 16-bit samples it's -32768..+32767. 2) Sure. Just keep in mind that any additional processing will add some latency, if that's important to you. 3) Asking for people's opinions is off-topic here at StackOverflow. Try implementing it in the way that seems the most straight-forward to you. You can always improve on it later if necessary.